# Add to Cart in WooCommerce from Embedded React Component

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce

I built a **React Component** that is embedded in a wordpress page in theme based website (Enfold theme to be precise).

The Component is allows users to render different art works on a wall.

I have the product ids and variation ids of all items that are rendered on the wall in a JSON.

How do I add all these items to the cart?

I tried looking a lot online closest I found was [this](https://dsgnwrks.pro/snippets/woocommerce-allow-adding-multiple-products-to-the-cart-via-the-add-to-cart-query-string/) solution.

But code mentioned in the link to be added in functions.php breaks my site.

I'm using Wordpress `5.2.5` and Woocommerce `3.7.0`.

Any direction would be great help. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please post some codes to be declared the problem

Comment: Hey my code is irrelevant because I just need to add to cart in a woocommerce website. Also the link I mentioned has a solution but it doesn't work may be because it works with older versions of wordpress. The problem is I can't really understand that code and can't understand what's breaking the site.